# CSS / jQuery - Limit the number of characters for all dynamically generated textbox

Tags: jquery, css, jeditable

I am using jEditable for inline edit, so when user double click a text, it will turns into a textbox.

I need to limit the number characters users can enter into the textbox, but since the textbox is generated from the plugin, I could not use the inline styling like this:

```
 <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="100" />
```

Any idea how I can style all textboxes in css so user cannot input more than 30 characters?

Thanks a lot...

Comment: You could calculate the width of 30 characters worth of text with a specific font, then make that the width of the text box. That's IF you want to do it in CSS..

Comment: Hi, i already limit the width of the textbox, but I think the plugin seems to have the autogrow function, so i still can type in as much character as i want...

Comment: Look at the "Character counter" section on this page: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/custom.html

Comment: hi, thanks, i came across that too. But since my data is all display in a table, I wish not to display the message "30 characters left" while editing.. wonder is there anyway i can limit the number of characters without display that? thanks so much...

Comment: `.charcounter{ display:none; }` in your css

Comment: hi, using type=charcounter turns my textbox into a textarea and alter the styling... any other suggestion?? thanks a lot...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4814/discussion-between-charlie-and-user834754)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a bit confused.  If you're already using jQuery, is there a reason not to use it to limit the length?

http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/TvDvd/2/

```
$('body').delegate('input[type="text"]','focus', function() {
    $(this).attr('maxLength',100);
});
```

Limit text areas also, just incase jEditable uses that: http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/TvDvd/3/

```
$('body').delegate('input[type="text"], textarea','focus', function() {
    $(this).attr('maxLength',100);
});
```

Comment: HI, thanks, I am looking for something like this. This works for all "normal" text box, but yet the jeditable textbox is not being restricted...

Comment: Hi, i got it work at jeditable by removing the type="text".. Thanks!

Comment: @user834754: maybe jEditable uses text area, try the updated code

Comment: Not sure it's working in IE that why I've put an event added to the maxlength

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do something like that :

```
$('input').attr('maxLength','25').keypress(maxLength);

function maxLength(e) {
    if(window.event) // IE
    {
        keynum = e.keyCode
    }
    else if(e.which) // Netscape/Firefox/Opera
    {
        keynum = e.which
    }


    if (keynum  == 8) { return true; }
        return this.value.length < $(this).attr("maxLength");
}
```